# Why onCancel test is failing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I've written two tests; one to test the Download button and the other to test the Cancel button. Why is the Cancel test failing?

Here is the code I am trying to run two simple tests on the Download (handleDownload) and cancel (handleCancel) buttons.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalFooter } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Select from 'controls/Select/Select';
import { getModalRoot } from 'sd/components/layout/admin/forms/FvReplaceFormModal/helpers';
import { DOWNLOAD_BUTTON_TEXT, CANCEL_BUTTON_TEXT } from 'sd/constants/ModalWindowConstants';

import 'sd/components/layout/admin/forms/FvReplaceFormModal/style.scss';
import type { SelectOption } from 'shared/types/General';

const { Body: ModalBody, Header: ModalHeader, Title: ModalTitle } = Modal;

export interface ChooseLanguageModalProps {
    languageList: SelectOption[];
    onDownloadLanguage: (value?: string) => void;
    onDownload: () => void;
    onCancel?: () => void;
}

const HEADER_TITLE = 'Choose language page';
const CHOOSE_LANGUAGE_LABEL = 'Choose language';

export const ChooseLanguageModal = (props: ChooseLanguageModalProps) => {
    const { languageList } = props;

    const onChangeLanguage = (value?: string | undefined) => {
        const { onDownloadLanguage } = props;
        onDownloadLanguage(value);
    };

    const handleCancel = async () => {
        await hideChooseLanguageModal();
    };

    const handleDownload = async () => {
        const { onDownload } = props;
        onDownload();

        await hideChooseLanguageModal();
    };

    return (
        <Modal
            show
            backdrop="static"
            animation={false}
            container={getModalRoot()}
            onHide={() => hideChooseLanguageModal()}
        >
            <ModalHeader closeButton>
                <ModalTitle>{HEADER_TITLE}</ModalTitle>
            </ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
                <div>
                    <p>This project has one or more languages set up in the Translation Manager.</p>
                    <p>
                        To download the translation in the BRD export, select one language from the drop-down below.
                        English will always be shown as the base language.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        If a language is selected, additional columns will be added to display the appropriate
                        translation for labels, rules and text messages.
                    </p>
                    <p>You may click Download without selecting a language to export the default language.</p>
                </div>
                <div>{CHOOSE_LANGUAGE_LABEL}</div>
                <div>
                    <Select
                        clearable={false}
                        canEnterFreeText={false}
                        searchable={false}
                        options={languageList}
                        onChange={onChangeLanguage}
                    />
                </div>
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
                <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={handleDownload}>
                    {DOWNLOAD_BUTTON_TEXT}
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={handleCancel}>{CANCEL_BUTTON_TEXT}</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
    );
};

export async function showChooseLanguageModal(props: ChooseLanguageModalProps): Promise<void> {
    await ReactDOM.render(<ChooseLanguageModal {...props} />, getModalRoot());
}

export async function hideChooseLanguageModal(): Promise<void> {
    const modalRoot = getModalRoot();
    modalRoot && ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(modalRoot);
}
```

Here are the tests that I've written.

```
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

import { ChooseLanguageModal } from '../ChooseLanguageWindow.react';

describe('ChooseLanguageModal', () => {
    const languageList = [
        { id: '1', value: 'en', name: 'English' },
        { id: '2', value: 'fr', name: 'French' },
        { id: '3', value: 'es', name: 'Spanish' },
    ];
    const onDownloadLanguage = jest.fn();
    const handleDownload = jest.fn();
    const handleCancel = jest.fn();

    test('should call onDownload when download button is clicked', async () => {
        await act(async () => {
            render(
                <ChooseLanguageModal
                    languageList={languageList}
                    onDownloadLanguage={onDownloadLanguage}
                    onDownload={handleDownload}
                    onCancel={handleCancel}
                />
            );
        });

        const downloadButton = screen.getByText('Download');
        fireEvent.click(downloadButton);

        expect(handleDownload).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    test('should call onCancel when cancel button is clicked', async () => {
        await act(async () => {
            render(
                <ChooseLanguageModal
                    languageList={languageList}
                    onDownloadLanguage={onDownloadLanguage}
                    onDownload={handleDownload}
                    onCancel={handleCancel}
                />
            );
        });

        const cancelButton = screen.getByText('Cancel');
        fireEvent.click(cancelButton);

        expect(handleCancel).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

You'll notice that both tests are closely identical, obviously except for the fireEvent. It fails every time.

```
ChooseLanguageModal › should call onCancel when cancel button is clicked

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      48 |         fireEvent.click(cancelButton);
      49 |
    > 50 |         expect(handleCancel).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                              ^
      51 |     });
      52 | });
      53 |
```

I've tried running only the onCancel test but it still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCancel` is not used at all in your `ChooseLanguageModal` component. It is accepted in the types, but it is never passed to anything and never called inside of your own component either. Your test is currently correctly failing because the application doesn't work according to the test specification.

Call it as you expect, which was probably intended to be in `handleCancel`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalFooter } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Select from 'controls/Select/Select';
import { getModalRoot } from 'sd/components/layout/admin/forms/FvReplaceFormModal/helpers';
import { DOWNLOAD_BUTTON_TEXT, CANCEL_BUTTON_TEXT } from 'sd/constants/ModalWindowConstants';

import 'sd/components/layout/admin/forms/FvReplaceFormModal/style.scss';
import type { SelectOption } from 'shared/types/General';

const { Body: ModalBody, Header: ModalHeader, Title: ModalTitle } = Modal;

export interface ChooseLanguageModalProps {
    languageList: SelectOption[];
    onDownloadLanguage: (value?: string) => void;
    onDownload: () => void;
    onCancel?: () => void;
}

const HEADER_TITLE = 'Choose language page';
const CHOOSE_LANGUAGE_LABEL = 'Choose language';

export const ChooseLanguageModal = (props: ChooseLanguageModalProps) => {
    const { languageList, onCancel } = props;

    const onChangeLanguage = (value?: string | undefined) => {
        const { onDownloadLanguage } = props;
        onDownloadLanguage(value);
    };

    const handleCancel = async () => {
        onCancel()
        await hideChooseLanguageModal();
    };

    const handleDownload = async () => {
        const { onDownload } = props;
        onDownload();

        await hideChooseLanguageModal();
    };

    return (
        <Modal
            show
            backdrop="static"
            animation={false}
            container={getModalRoot()}
            onHide={() => hideChooseLanguageModal()}
        >
            <ModalHeader closeButton>
                <ModalTitle>{HEADER_TITLE}</ModalTitle>
            </ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
                <div>
                    <p>This project has one or more languages set up in the Translation Manager.</p>
                    <p>
                        To download the translation in the BRD export, select one language from the drop-down below.
                        English will always be shown as the base language.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        If a language is selected, additional columns will be added to display the appropriate
                        translation for labels, rules and text messages.
                    </p>
                    <p>You may click Download without selecting a language to export the default language.</p>
                </div>
                <div>{CHOOSE_LANGUAGE_LABEL}</div>
                <div>
                    <Select
                        clearable={false}
                        canEnterFreeText={false}
                        searchable={false}
                        options={languageList}
                        onChange={onChangeLanguage}
                    />
                </div>
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
                <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={handleDownload}>
                    {DOWNLOAD_BUTTON_TEXT}
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={handleCancel}>{CANCEL_BUTTON_TEXT}</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
    );
};

export async function showChooseLanguageModal(props: ChooseLanguageModalProps): Promise<void> {
    await ReactDOM.render(<ChooseLanguageModal {...props} />, getModalRoot());
}

export async function hideChooseLanguageModal(): Promise<void> {
    const modalRoot = getModalRoot();
    modalRoot && ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(modalRoot);
}
```